# Solve the equation (very hard)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How to find all irrational solutions of the equation
$$\frac{156x^6-624x^4}{212x^6-264x^4+14x^2-1}=\frac{1}{1+x\cos{\frac{4\pi}{9}}}+\frac{1}{1+x\cos{\frac{2\pi}{9}}}+\frac{1}{1-x\cos{\frac{\pi}{9}}}$$

I have no any idea.

### Thanks in advances.

Now I have a solution.

Let $a=\cos\frac{\pi}{9}$, $a=\cos\frac{2\pi}{9}$, $a=\cos\frac{4\pi}{9}$.

It is not very difficult to show that $abc=\frac{1}{8}$, $ab+ac-bc=\frac{3}{4}$, and $a-b-c=0$.

So we can simplify  $$\frac{1}{1+x\cos{\frac{3\pi}{9}}}+\frac{1}{1+x\cos{\frac{2\pi}{9}}}+\frac{1}{1-x\cos{\frac{\pi}{9}}}=\frac{-\frac{3x^3}{4}+3}{-\frac{x^3}{8}-\frac{3x^2}{4}+1}$$
From the equation we get 
$$\frac{156x^6-624x^4}{212x^6-264x^4+14x^2-1}=\frac{-\frac{3x^3}{4}+3}{-\frac{x^3}{8}-\frac{3x^2}{4}+1}$$
which impiles 
$$6(x^2-4)\left(\frac{1}{x^3+6x^2-8}+\frac{26x^4}{-212x^6+264x^4-14x^2+1} \right)=0$$
Since $x$ is irrational,
$$\frac{1}{x^3+6x^2-8}+\frac{26x^4}{-212x^6+264x^4-14x^2+1} =0$$
That is $$26x^7-56x^6+56x^4-14x^2+1=0$$
Replacing $x$ by $\frac{t}{t^2+2}$, finally we get
$$t^{14}+26t^7+128=0$$
Therefore $t^7 = -13\pm\sqrt{41} \Rightarrow t=-(13\pm\sqrt{41})^\frac{1}{7} $

Hence, $x=\dfrac{1}{t+\frac{2}{t}}=\dfrac{-1}{(13+\sqrt{41})^\frac{1}{7}+(13-\sqrt{41})^\frac{1}{7}}$

Comment: Are you asking for approximate solutions or exact ones? This clearly multiplies out to a polynomial equation of degree greater than four, which does not in general have closed-form solutions.

Comment: I'm asking for exact value.

Comment: So, you ask for the exact solutions of the roots of a polynomial of degree 9 with irrational coefficients. Is this correct ?

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe this should have an exact solution that is expressible in radicals?

Comment: Who give me this problem have exact solutions

Comment: i have found five real solutions of degree nine

Comment: are these solutions are the right solutions?

Comment: @Bless Do you have any reason to believe this person's claim of having exact solutions? :).  Does the obscure rational function on the left have any meaning?

Comment: @Doc. "i have found five real solutions of degree nine" The "degree" of a solution meaning what?

Comment: Now I have an irrational exact solution

Comment: $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}(a-b)}$ , where $a=(\frac{\sqrt{41}-13}{2\sqrt{2}})^\frac{1}{7}$,  $b=(\frac{\sqrt{41}+13}{2\sqrt{2}})^\frac{1}{7}$

Comment: @Bless can you prove it?

Comment: how could $\cos(\pi/9)=\cos(2\pi/9)=\cos(4\pi/9)$?

Comment: $\frac{1}{1+x\cos(3\pi/9)}$ was not simplified to $\frac{1}{1+x\cos(\pi/3)}$?

Comment: if i have written this the downvoting would be $-\infty$!!!